# Como posso fazer um consulta C# numa base de dados SQL Server

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, projeto-de-software

Tenho um projeto em desenvolvimento neste percurso de estágio e portanto estou a trabalhar em coisas novas. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer em C# uma consulta de dados presentes em tabelas SQL Server. Desculpem se estiver a ser muito vago.

Comment: Não é uma pergunta adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software**. Sugiro remover esta marca para facilitar a localização de questões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rapaz, vários caminhos levam a Roma...

Vc pode usar o ADO.NET, o Dapper ou algum ORM mais complexo. Tipo Nhibernate e Entity framework...

Ao que parece seu conhecimento é bem básico... Vc tem um caminho grande pela frente... Quer uma dica? Eu não faria por ADO.NET... eu começaria com Dapper e depois migraria para o NH ou EF.

Não conheço quem use ADO.NET profissionalmente hj em dia....

Bem a página pra começar a entender o Dapper.net é essa.
https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Mas se ficar perdido, é melhor começar do zero....
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Obrigado.
Sim o meu conhecimento nesta linguagem é muito básico.

Comment: O objetivo seria fazer uma aplicação .exe

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias formas de se fazer isso como não especificou qual desenvolvimento seria Web ou Desktop, no caso se é um app Web poderia fazer assim usando o EntityFramework no seu contexto faça assim:

```
   public List<GetPersonResult> GetPeople()
 {
       return (from p in dbContext.People
              select new GetPersonResult
              {
                   UserName = p.Username,
                   EmailAddress = p.Email
              }).ToList();
 }

 public class GetPersonResult
 {
       public string UserName{get;set;}
       public string EmailAddress{get;set;}
 }
```

Especifique melhor qual ambiente Web ou Desktop..blz